# In tab view I want to refresh Fragment every change

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_viewpager);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_tabs);
setupViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

 public void setupViewPager(ViewPager upViewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new ViewTodayFragment(),"Daily");
        adapter.addFrag(new ViewWeekFragment(),"Weekly");
        adapter.addFrag(new ViewMonthFragment(),"Monthly");
        adapter.addFrag(new ViewYearFragment(),"Yearly");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I want to refresh fragment every time when tab changing.

inside fragment this is my code

```
public class ViewTodayFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    View v;
    ListView listview;
    private ArrayList<DailyModel> mItems;
    public static String datesel="a";

    public ViewTodayFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_today, container, false);
        recyclerView =(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.view_today_lv_today);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        loadData();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadData();
    }

    public void loadData(){
        mItems=new ArrayList<DailyModel>();
        List<Income> ll = null;
        Log.d("ALLL",datesel);
        if(datesel.equals("a")){
            Calendar cw = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String currentDay=format1.format(cw.getTime());
            ll=new IncomeHandler(getActivity()).getIncomeByThisDay(currentDay);
        }else{
            ll=new IncomeHandler(getActivity()).getIncomeByThisDay(datesel);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); i++) {
            DailyModel a=new DailyModel();
            a.setCategory(ll.get(i).getWay());
            a.setDescription(ll.get(i).getDes());
            a.setType(ll.get(i).getType());
            a.setBank("Bank");
            a.setAmount(ll.get(i).getAmount());
            mItems.add(a);
        }
        mAdapter = new DailyAdapter(mItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

So like this there are 4 tabs so i want to refresh every time it change the tab.I try to do that inside OnResume().But it also not working.

Comment: share your code in which you are adding fragment in tab layout..

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Create your pager adapter like this.

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
      private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

    public void addFragmentTitle(String title) {
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return new ViewTodayFragment();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new ViewWeekFragment();
            } else if(position == 2){
                return new ViewMonthFragment();
            } else{
                return new ViewYearFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    }
```

Now you need to add fragment like this

```
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter .addFragmentTitle("Daily");
//..... add rest of the fragment title.
 viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter );
```

hope this will help you. though i didn't try this. just writing please let me know if you get any error.

Comment: i think it should be adapter.addFragmentTitle("Daily");

Comment: let me check wait a moment

Comment: try this viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); and check

Comment: No still not refresh.

Comment: check the answer i have updated the code.. hope it will work now

Comment: if the solution wont work then Implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener and use this on page change..viewPage.setAdapter( adapter ); though its a work around. but i hope it will definitely solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved this type issue currently.Please reffer my Code line by line.it might be Help you.

Thanks.

```
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;


viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_viewpager);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_tabs);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_tabs);
setupViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            adapter.getItem(position).onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });


public void setupViewPager(ViewPager upViewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new ViewTodayFragment(),"Daily");
    adapter.addFrag(new ViewWeekFragment(),"Weekly");
    adapter.addFrag(new ViewMonthFragment(),"Monthly");
    adapter.addFrag(new ViewYearFragment(),"Yearly");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem. My four tabs (a sports timer with athletes - skiers or cyclsits - starting at intervals) also needed to communicate with each other. For example once a race is started, the set up controls must be disabled. 
My project was based on Google's SlidingTabsColors sample.
I created a simple, one method interface called `Refreshable` and each of my tabs (Fragments) implemented its `refresh` method.
In my SlidingTabsFragment (extends Fragment) I override `instantiateItem` so I can capture a reference to each tab's fragment.

```
        // Here we can safely save a reference to the created
        // Fragment, no matter where it came from (either getItem() or
        // FragmentManger).
        //
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);

            /**
             * Save Fragment references in an array with the MainActivity
             * so that other tabs can be refreshed (state updated) depending on
             * changes to other tabs.
             */
            MainActivity a = (MainActivity)getActivity();
            a.addFragment((Refreshable)createdFragment);
            return createdFragment;
        }
```

My main is an observer of my data model, but yours may different.

This is the main's method to "register" the fragments.

```
     /**
     * Accepts the specified fragment and adds to the list of "Refreshable" Fragments.
     * If it is already registered, it is not added a second time.
     *
     * @param fragment
     *            the Fragment (Observer) to add.
     */
    public void addFragment(Refreshable fragment) {
        if (fragment == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("fragment == null");
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            if (!mRefreshables.contains(fragment))
                mRefreshables.add(fragment);
        }
    }
```

In my case, this code is in the `update` method of my Observer. My data has changed (race started, interval countdown expired, finisher recorded) and I can refresh all tabs. I cannot call from one tab to another because of race (no pun intended) conditions.

```
/**
 * Call refresh on every Fragment to update state.
 */

for (Refreshable refreshable : array) {
    refreshable.refresh();
}
```

Each tab's refresh method does its own thing.

You may not need an Observer co-ordinating all tabs, but at least you'll have a reference to them and a method other than onResume (which didn't work for me either) to call and have the content refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

your answer....you must use

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

when your selected tab is change.